Problema al implementar juego de adivinar palabras en JavaScript con interacción HTML
Estoy desarrollando un juego simple de adivinar palabras en JavaScript que se integra con HTML para la interfaz de usuario. El juego permite al usuario ingresar un intento y verificar si coincide con la palabra objetivo. El código que he escrito está arriba, pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas, especialmente al mostrar la palabra a medida que el usuario hace intentos. ¿Alguien podría revisar mi código porfavor y sugerir mejoras para que funcione correctamente el juego de adivinar palabras en mi aplicación web?
`function intentar (intento){`
`if(palabra === intento);{`
    `console.log("GANASTE");`
`}else{`
    `intentos = intentos - 1;`
   `console.log("te quedan", intentos, "intentos")` 
    `for(pos in palabra){`
        `console.log("mensaje", pos);`
    `if(intento[pos]===palabra[pos]){`
        `console.log(intento[pos], "verde");`
    `}else if(palabra.includes(intento[pos])){`
        `console.log(intento[pos], "amarillo");`
    `}else{`
        `console.log(intento[pos], "gris");`
    }
 }
        

    `if(intento[1]===palabra[1]){`
        `console.log(intento[1], "verde");`
    `}else if(palabra.includes(intento[1])){`
        console.log(intento[1], "amarillo");
    `}else{`
        `console.log(intento[1], "gris");
    }`
        


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! ese codigo esta incompleto.. no?

Creo que tienes una buena idea, pero tienes varios problemas.
Ignorando los ` que colocaste en el código, probablemente tratando de publicarlo, encuentro varios errores:

Tienes un punto y coma de más aquí: if(palabra === intento);{. Luego del if() va la llave de apertura, sin puntos y comas.

La indentación está muy mal. La computadora no necesita de indentación, de hecho, puedes escribir todo un programa en una línea, o todo pegado al margen izquierdo. La indentación te ayuda a TI y a otros seres humanos a entender mejor el programa.
Diría que por la misma razón, a tu función le están haciendo falta un par de llaves de cierre, que he agregado.
Sobra decir que he corregido la indentación, usando dos espacios para cada nivel.

Cuándo vas viendo cada posición e imprimiendo los colores, si la palabra introducida por el usuario tiene menor longitud que la buscada, no lo detectas y comienzas a acceder a posiciones que no existen en la cadena, lo que da como resultado undefined, que no se entiende en la salida. Puse un if para ese caso.

Puedo ver que las últimas líneas de código, que tienen la posición fija [1] probablemente vengan de una prueba anterior, pero no tienen que ver con el código que va recorriendo la cadena, simplemente las he quitado.


Lo que queda es esta función, que he mandado a llamar con algunas palabras de ejemplo para que veas tu misma cómo funciona:


const palabra = 'helado';
let intentos = 10;

function intentar (intento) {
  if(palabra === intento) {
    console.log("GANASTE");
  } else {
    intentos = intentos - 1;
    console.log("te quedan", intentos, "intentos")
    for(pos in palabra) {
      if(intento[pos]===palabra[pos]) {
        console.log(intento[pos], "verde");
      } else if(palabra.includes(intento[pos])) {
        console.log(intento[pos], "amarillo");
      } else if (pos < intento.length) {
        console.log(intento[pos], "gris");
      } else {
        console.log('_', "gris");
      }
    }
  }
}

intentar('hola');
intentar('hala');
intentar('hila');
intentar('helar');
intentar('helada');
intentar('helado');
  



Dado que no hay una especificación, no hay manera de saber si esto es correcto, pero considero que lograr que el código se ejecute ya es un paso hacia adelante y, luego, ya irás desarrollando la lógica necesaria para que funcione según lo has diseñado, o según te lo han pedido.
